# Scala split a multi line string by lines that contain all hyphens

Tags: regex, scala, split

I have a multiline string that contains:

```
this is line 1

------------------------------

this is line 2

+++++++++++++++++++++++++

this is line 3 

---------------

this is line 4
```

I want to divide this string into chunks by splitting on lines that contains only (-,+), I tried regular expression (^++$)|(^-+$) that worked fine on regex validators, but it's not working in Scala.

Comment: Use `"""(?m)(^\++$)|(^-+$)"""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a multiline modifier to make `^` match the start of a line and `$` to match the end of the line. Also, enclosing the pattern with `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) will trim the items in the resulting list:

```
val rx = """(?m)\s*^(\++|-+)$\s*"""
val res = text.split(rx)
print(res.toList)
// => List(this is line 1, this is line 2, this is line 3, this is line 4)
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/02e343)

Note I also shortened the pattern by using a single grouping construct like `^(\++|-+)$`. It matches the start of a line, then 1+ plus or hyphen symbols, and then end of a line (thus, no need repeating `^` and `$`).

Another solution can be splitting the string with line breaks, and then filtering out empty lines, or the lines that only contain plus or hyphen only symbols:

```
print(text.split("\\r?\\n").filter(line=>line.matches("""(\++|-+)?""") == false).toList)
// => List(this is line 1, this is line 2, this is line 3 , this is line 4)
```

See [another Scala demo](http://ideone.com/E3TE3e)