# Scala Split multi line String by at least two concecutive line breaks (\r\n\r\n) and several separators printed on one line

Tags: regex, scala, split

I have the following multi Line String:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: 
---- ----------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
--------------------------------------------------------
-- test2

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `test`
--
```

This is a follow up to a question ([Scala split a multi line string by lines that contain all hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454775/scala-split-a-multi-line-string-by-lines-that-contain-all-hyphens))

I want to split this string by all hyphens (works) and empty lines separating text chunks, I tried (?m)(\r?\n\r?\n+)|(?m)(^(++|-+|=+|#+|_+|[--+]|-- -+)$) which works fine for hyphens but doesn't split on empty lines.

Comment: Try `"""(?m)\s*^(?:([-+=#_])\1+|\s)+$\s*"""`

Comment: I tried it, but the line containing "-- test2" wasn't separated from the following lines, also if you can please elaborate on the solution.

Comment: Do you mean the `-- test2` line must be removed? Then, `-- Host: localhost    Database:` and `-- Server version   5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` must be removed, too

Comment: what I mean is that line should be a separate element in the Array, because now it's concatenated with the lines that start with "/*40101...."

Comment: [I do not observe the same behavior](http://ideone.com/SXZtHG). Also, try [another approach, `"""(?m)\s*^(?:([-+=#_])\1+|(?:\r?\n){2,})$\s*"""`](http://ideone.com/9KALce).

Comment: if you look at the output you'll see that --test2 is followed by an empty line and then the lines that follow all as one element

Comment: Check [this one](http://ideone.com/m0MWNz).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, it does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
val rx = """(?m)\s*^(?:([-+=#_])\1+|\s)+$\s*|(?:\r?\n)+"""
val res = text.split(rx)
print(res.toList.foreach(println))
```

Output of the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/xR0Zjl):

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64)
-- Host: localhost    Database:
-- Server version   5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
-- test2
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
-- Current Database: `test`
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier making `^` match the start of line and `$` match the end of line
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces before the start of a line
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:([-+=#_])\1+|\s)+` - any line containing whitespace  symbols and/or repeated consecutive `-`, `+`, `=`, `#`, `_` symbols
- `$` - end of line
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces before the start of a line
- `|` - or
- `(?:\r?\n)+` - 1 or more line breaks (`CRLF` or `LF` style).

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/BskiqD/1).